# How do you "dismantle" the word "pneumonoultramicrosilicovolcanoconiosis"?

Tags: meaning

By my guess, the word "pneumonoultramicrosilicovolcanoconiosis" is a combination of different suffixes and prefixes. Can anyone tell me how to "dismantle" the word?

Comment: Did you mean "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis"?

Comment: You could have easily found the answer on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis#Etymology (searching on google would have corrected the missing "scopic")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This word can be split into 6 parts:
pneumono, ultra, micro, silico, volcano, coniosis

- Pneumono - used like a prefix meaning "lung", comes from the Greek word pneúmōn
- Ultra - means "very"
- Micro - means "extremely small", such as microwave
- Silico - means "of silicates"
- Volcano - this one's easy, it means "of volcanos"
- Coniosis - any of various diseases or pathological conditions caused by dust

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you subsituted *scopic* for *silico*; otherwise the answer is fine. That is, *scopic* doesn't appear in the original word.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Oh yes, I didn't notice that, thanks!

Comment: You can edit the answer, you know.

Comment: The actual word has both _scopic_ and _silico_ though. [Listing from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty The word contained "scopic" every time I've seen it.  I think it may be an error in the question.

Comment: "coniosis" -- "coni": dust, from Greek, and "osis": disease.

Answer (score 32):

This is a joke word!

```
pneumono  ultra  micro  silico        volcano      coni    osis
of breath very   small  of slicates   of volcanos  dust    disease
```

So it is a breathing disease cause by very small pieces of silicates that are produced by volcanos (ie volcanic dust)

But it is a *joke* about how doctors make up long words for diseases.  It's not a word that is ever used, except as an example of a very long word. It was invented by Everett M. Smith, president of the National Puzzlers' League, not a doctor.

On the other hand pneumoconiosis is a real disease, and may be caused by asbestos, coal dust, or breathing other types of dust.

However, as pointed out in a comment the word is spelled "wrong" in the question it should be "...ultramicroscopicsilico..."

This contains "microscopic", which means "smaller than can be seen with the naked eye".

```
pneumono  ultra  microscopic      silico        volcano      coni    osis
of breath very   invisibly small  of slicates   of volcanos  dust    disease
```

Comment: And, notably, the variety of pneumoconiosis the word theoretically describes actually does exist, but there is no more specific single word for it than pneumoconiosis (unlike, for example, asbestosis, which is the specific variety caused by inhalation of asbestos fibres).